# Flutter redirect when encountered http 401

Tags: flutter

I have a navigation like this for now:

`main > app > account > address`

right now i encountered issue if user fetching address and their session expires how can I redirect them back to login page? Still new to flutter, can't find the esolution how to send unauthenticated status to `main` so it can redirect it.

I'm using dio and MobX package.

```
 dio.interceptors
        .add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      String token = prefs.getString('access_token');

      if (token != null) {
        options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
      }

      options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

      return options; //continue
    }, onResponse: (Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      var results = {};

      if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 201 || statusCode == 204) {
        final dynamic decodeResponse = this.decodeResponse(response);
        bool responseIsList = decodeResponse is List;

        if (!responseIsList && decodeResponse['token'] != null) {
          final token = decodeResponse['token'];
          setAuthorizationToken(token['access_token'], token['refresh_token']);
        }

        if (responseIsList) {
          return decodeResponse;
        } else {
          final resultToAdd = decodeResponse;

          results.addAll(resultToAdd);

          return results;
        }
      }

      return response;
    }, onError: (DioError e) async {
      final r = e.response;
      if (r.statusCode == 401) {
        AuthStore().unauthorize(prefs: _sharedPreferences);
      }

      if (r != null) {
        return {"has_error": true, ...r.data};
      }
      // Do something with response error
      return e;
    }));
```

I've tried to put Observer on my `main.dart` to keep checking on the status

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Observer(builder: (_) {

  if (store.statusAuth == 401) {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/'); // this is error
  } 


  // other material app function
});
```

Any solution?

The solution only I can think of for now is checking every time API is called (every store). if 401 will automatically send it back to login page. but this approach will be very redundant.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. To resolve this issue, we need a **Navigation** without *context* to can navigate on **interceptors**.
Api service is initializated before MaterialApp. MaterialApp is allowed pass the navigatorKey for top navigator.

I create **GlobalKey** when define interceptors of apiservice and use it for return MaterialApp.

```
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigator;//Create a key for navigator
```

and create apiService

```
void _configAuthApiService() {
    ...
    if (error.response?.statusCode == 401) {
        navigator.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('/login');
    }
    ...
}
```

When create material app:

```
MaterialApp(
    ...
    navigatorKey: navigator,
    ...
)
```

Comment: How do you get the `navigator` inside of the `_configAuthApiService`?

Comment: I put _navigator_  to contructor of _ApiService_.

Comment: Thanks but did not help me.